# Change a File's ACL to Allow Full Access for Everyone

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pinvoke, acl

How do I change a file's owner to `Everyone` and also allow the `Everyone` object `Full Access`?

Are there any APIs available for this? Do I have to use P/Invoke?

I searched everywhere but can't find anything to do this.

Comment: You cannot make Everyone be the owner of an object

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe you are wrong. Try setting the owner manually using the Security tab in the file properties. It will let you set the owner to Everyone without any trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, there are API's available for this. You may want to have a look at the [File.SetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx) method in the System.IO namespace.

```cs
// Read the current ACL details for the file
var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

// Create a new rule set, based on "Everyone"
var fileAccessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(new NTAccount("", "Everyone"),
      FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
      AccessControlType.Allow);

// Append the new rule set to the file
fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(fileAccessRule);

// And persist it to the filesystem
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fileSecurity);
```

The forementioned article has tons of great things to play with, regarding the ACL.

Comment: With `fileSecurity.SetOwner` you can.

Comment: You should use `new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)` instead of `new NTAccount(...)`, because the string `"Everyone"` is localized, turns out (i.e. it's different on non-English OS!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`FileInfo.GetAccessControl`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.getaccesscontrol.aspx) and [**`File.SetAccessControl`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx) methods

check the sample code given in MSDN link for [`File.SetAccessControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx)